# Repeatedly check whether integer input has leading zeroes

Tags: java

I need the user to enter an integer input, check whether it starts by 0 and tell the user to enter another integer if that is the case

I tried parsing the integer input to a string, that works but only once. The string cannot be edited when program loops

I think the solution should not at all involve strings because i need the program to loop and check over and over until the input is valid (ie has no leading zeroes)

Splitting each digit of the int into an array does not work also because the ways i found pass by string.

```
    public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);    
    int in= 0;
    boolean looper=true;
   
    while (looper == true) {
     System.out.println("Enter an integer");
    in = key.nextInt();
    /* check whether in has any leading zeroes, example of 
    wrong input: 09999, 0099*/
   
  if (/*in has no leading zeroes*/)
   looper = false;
}

key.close();
}
```

Maybe another answer would be to have a method that creates a brand new string every time the program loops, so maybe like a recursion that automatically creates strings, not sure if that's even a thing though.

Comment: "I think the solution should not at all involve strings".  You are mistaken.  If you want to read in the text entered by the user exactly, you should read it in as a `String`.  If you read it in as an `int`, leading zeroes will simply be ignored.

Comment: You have to input the data as a string to do that. You are reading the input as an integer, and an integer value doesn't have any leading zeroes, it's just the value.

Comment: The solution most must strings, if you take a look at Scanner.nextInt(), you can see that its parse a string into an Integer using ```Integer.parseInt```

Answer (score 1):

You can make it cleaner by using a `do-while` loop instead of `while(true)`. Note that an integer starting with `0` is an octal number e.g.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 06;
        System.out.println(x);

        // x = 09; // Compilation error - out of range
    }
}
```

Thus, `06` is a valid integer. For your requirement, you can input to a `String` variable and prompt the user to again if it starts with a zero. If the input does not start with a zero, try parsing it to an `int` and process it if it succeeds; otherwise, loopback e.g.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner key = new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = "";
        int in = 0;
        boolean valid = true;
        do {
            System.out.print("Enter an integer: ");
            input = key.nextLine();
            if (input.startsWith("0")) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input");
                valid = false;
            } else {
                try {
                    in = Integer.parseInt(input);
                    System.out.println("You entered " + in);
                    // ... process it
                    valid = true;
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input");
                    valid = false;
                }
            }
        } while (!valid);
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Enter an integer: 09999
Invalid input
Enter an integer: xyz
Invalid input
Enter an integer: 123
You entered 123
```

As an aside, never close a `Scanner(System.in)` because it also closes `System.in` and there is no way to open it without rebooting the JVM.